# php navigation using get or include

Tags: php, navigation

`index.php` is controlling the site. 
I have `elseif include` based on `variable $p`

right now `$p` does not have anything in it and i'm not understanding why.

Also is using `include` the industry standard or would `GET` be a better choice?

In the `header file` which is included on `index.php` but it just takes me to the page link instead of storing the page in `$p`

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    "home" => "HOME", 
    "services" => "SERVICES", 
    "employees" => "EMPLOYEES", 
    "contact" => "CONTACT"); 
$p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";
foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
    echo '<li ';
if ($p == $url) { echo '<li><a class="active" href="' . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($url)). '.php">' 
. htmlspecialchars($label) . '</a></li>'; } else { echo '<li><a href="' . $url . '.php">' . $label . '</a></li>'; } 
}
?>
```

This is the index.php file:

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

<?php 
    if ($p == "services") {
        include("services.php");
    } elseif($p == "employees") {
        include("employees.php");
    } elseif($p == "contact") {
        include("contact.php");
    } else {
        include("home.php");
    };
?>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Where is $p comming from? There has to be some kind of Form or something, which sends the $_GET['p']

Comment: so would it be acceptable to just go to the top of each page and say $p=page?

Comment: @NichoDiaz: Are you trying to include a file depending on the page the user is viewing?

Comment: yes im trying to understand how to do this. But I am also wondering if it would be better to just use GET? I just want the navigation to work give me an Active link and then either use GET or include depending on what ever the best and most common practice is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, however include and $_GET are two completely separate things.

$_GET is an array of the query string out of your URL. So, for instance, if your URL was mysite.com/index.php?a=rawr&p=services then $_GET would be array("a" => "rawr", "p" => "services"); If you don't have any parameters in your URL assigned to p, then $_GET["p"] would be empty

Source:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

EDIT:

I think I'm starting to understand your question now. Using your current method would be fine, I would just change up the code slightly:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    "home" => "HOME", 
    "services" => "SERVICES", 
    "employees" => "EMPLOYEES", 
    "contact" => "CONTACT"
); 
$p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";
foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
?>
<li><a <?= $p == $url ? 'class="active"' : ""?> href="index.php?p=<?=$url?>" > <?=$label?> </a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: right so, if I built the nav using GET all I need to do is add the page to $p then I can Use GET?

Comment: If you wanted to use GET and stick to your current method, your url would need to have index.php?p=services (or other page depending). Then, when you navigate to that URL and set $p = $_GET["p"], $p should equal whatever you had set p to in the URL (in this case services). I don't believe this is the most efficient way, however for your setup it will work. You might look into a PHP framework such as [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/) or a similar framework depending on your project needs

Comment: what is the best way to do this. regardless of my set up. What is the most effective way to make a nav bar.

Comment: @NichoDiaz I edited my response above. Sorry I think I was misunderstanding your question

Comment: thanks for your help. But it still just takes me to the page instead of just putting the file in my index page. 
I have an index page. onclick I want the file to be added to the index page. Then I want the link to become active. Right now when I click a link its just taking me to that page. I copy and pasted your code in and it continues to just take me to the page instead of inlcude

Comment: @NichoDiaz Ok, I added the GET parameters to the URL in my example above. See if that works

Comment: still does the same thing... :/

Comment: @NichoDiaz What does your URL look like after clicking one of the navigation links?

Comment: I see what your doing, its using GET to the url. instead of what it was doing. But the page is just going there instead of including.

Comment: @NichoDiaz I see. Sorry I keep understanding your question more and more as we go along lol. I've edited to URL again - this time it will always take you to index.php?p=yourspecificpage every time. See if that helps. Sorry it's been taking me a bit to understand what you've been wanting.

Comment: Is this the best way to make something like this? Like from a professional standpoint?

Comment: In truth, it depends on the size of your project. If this site will always have just these few pages, this is not a bad solution. It is small, easy, and it can work. If you are planning on expanding this project and it will be changing frequently in the future, it would certainly be worth looking into a PHP Framework as I listed above. [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com) is what I like to use although it can be a bit heavy (includes a lot of extras) if your project will not need them. Frameworks, however, usually include a lot of features that can assist in the creation of navigation

Comment: So honestly it just kind of boils down to the context of the project. If this site will always stay small and you won't need to modify the navigation often, this will work fine from a professional standpoint. If there is the chance for change, however, I would look at a more dynamic solution.

Comment: @NichoDiaz Sorry to keep continuing this on, however another thought could be to dynamically get all of your php files in the current directory instead of having an array you would have to update with future changes. PHP [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) could do this just by specifying the current directory. Example: `foreach(glob(__DIR__ . "/*.php") as $files)` _I.E. have not tested that exact code_

Comment: Awesome thanks for your input. no need to be sorry. That is exactly what I was looking for was a very light weight dynamic way to achieve this without building a new nav for each site I Build. I would love to see a working example of what you just specified in the last post. Using GET and glob dir.